# Как умножить подсписок на число?

Tags: python, список

Есть список a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6]], хочу умножить подсписок [1, 2, 3] на какое либо число, а затем снова распечатать массив а, но с изменением. Пытался как-то решить задачу, получилось это:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6]]
b = []
c = []
for i in a[0]:
    i = i * 2
    b.append(i)
c.append(b)
c.append(a[1])
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно такой вариант подойдет

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 8, 6]]

a[0] = [ x*2 for x in a[0] ]

print(a)
```